# XAML - Part of an image that is outside the page not visible when I bring it inside

Tags: image, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have an  and the stretch is set "UniformToFill". So a part of the image is outside of the page. And I created an animation that moves the page to the left by using its transform's TranslateX.
The problem is when I run the animation and the image moves left, but the part of the image that was outside the page, keeps invisible, black, doesn't render.
Any solution here?

Animation:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MoveBackground" Completed="MoveBackgroundAnimCompleted">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="MoveBackgroundX" To="-775" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Image:

```
    <Image x:Name="PageBackground" Source="Assets/black.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ImageFailed="PageBackground_ImageFailed" ImageOpened="PageBackground_ImageOpened" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="BackgroundTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that putting the image inside a Stackpanel.
What occurs is that the image is clipped to the LayoutRoot grid, and using the Translate of the RenderTransform moves the image but it keeps clipped as it was in it's original position.
The Stackpanel doesn't clip items that are inside.